# How to plot multiple lists on the same graph as one line?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib, data-visualization

I would like to create plot which will present variability of some parameter conected with particular geological "cake" layer. I have a profile with given top and bottom depth of each surface and value of some physical parameter for each layer. Top and bottom are in form of intervals (e.g. [0-5, 2]; [5-7, 1.8]; etc.).
I would like to have one graph with complete profile as a one continuous line.
Data is stored as a table in csv format with columns named as follows:
|TOP| |BOTTOM| |VALUE|

I've created lists with numbers to fill intervals with data needed for a graph. Now im stuck and I don't have an idea how to link lines to create one continuous profile.
Code which I've tried already looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as file:
    file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    headers = next(file)
    table = list(file) 
    result = []
    for line in table:
        top = float(line[0])
        bottom = float(line[1])
        value = float(line[2])
        l = np.arange(top, bottom+1, 1)
        Z = [value]*len(l)

        ax.plot(Z, l)
        ax = plt.axes()
    #ax.set_ylim([55,-1])
    #ax.set_xlim([1,3])
    plt.show()
```

My results are are presented at fig 1., but I would like to obtain something similar to fig 2.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kib4g.jpg

I'm using Spyder 3.6.

Is it possible to create a single continuous line from different lists?
I am not attached to this solution. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: And I also found that script doesn't start to draw the line from first interval/layer...

Comment: Just checking if I understand correctly: you want your vertical lines from Figure 1 to be linked together with horizontal lines?

Comment: @Francisca yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot horizontal lines between your vertical bars using `hlines` (made up some fake data to look similar to yours):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

random_data = [5, 8, 17, 25, 32, 50]
values = [1.5, 2.3, 1.7, 2.5, 1.8, 1.8]  # Note last value should be duplicate

for i in range(len(random_data) - 1):
        top = float(random_data[i])
        bottom = float(random_data[i + 1])
        value = float(values[i])
        value_next = float(values[i + 1])

        l = np.arange(top, bottom + 1, 1)
        Z = [value]*len(l)

        pyplot.plot(Z, l)
        pyplot.hlines(bottom, value, value_next)

pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Note that you can also plot your vertical lines more easily using `vlines`:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

random_data = [5, 8, 17, 25, 32, 50]
values = [1.5, 2.3, 1.7, 2.5, 1.8, 1.8]  # Note last value should be duplicate

for i in range(len(random_data) - 1):
        top = float(random_data[i])
        bottom = float(random_data[i + 1])
        value = float(values[i])
        value_next = float(values[i + 1])

        pyplot.vlines(value, top, bottom)
        pyplot.hlines(bottom, value, value_next)

pyplot.show()
```

[image]

You might need to play around with data limits, but this will give you what you want.

Comment: After setting the data limits, it works perfectly! Thank you very much!